# Salesforce Active Logged In User Browser in User Report

Tags: browser, ie-11

I ran a report in Salesforce to find what browsers are used by Active Users with a logged in date filter of Today.
I always use Chrome, never IE. On my windows 10, under setup > Control Panel, the default is Chrome. Yet the report shows the browser  as IE11

When I go to Salesforce Setup > USers > Login History > downloaded the last 6 months history. The browser is Chrome.

What does the report show 'IE 11' ?

[image]

Comment: Do you have/use a tool like IETab (for Chrome) that changes the User-Agent string in the HTTP request? Are you using the Salesforce-provided DataLoader at all?

Comment: Do you have/use a tool like IETab (for Chrome) that changes the User-Agent string in the HTTP request?   No

Are you using the Salesforce-provided DataLoader at all?  = Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging in with the Salesforce-provided Data Loader shows up as being IE11 in the login history, just seems to be a part of how that tool is built.

You can tell it's DataLoader by looking at the "Application" column (which I don't see in my org, I had to download the 6 month login history to see it in the csv file).

Alternatively, the "Login Type" being either *Remote Access 2.0* or *Remote Access Client* is another indicator (though you'd see that login type for anything that uses a connected app to authenticate with Salesforce).